# Legal obstacles to moving out of parents' home and renting an apartment

Tags: rent, family-law

I am 22 and live with my parents but am planning to move out soon. My parents are uncooperative with preparing me for this stuff (they have refused to take me to get my driver's license), but circumstances may soon force to leave them, so I'm evaluating options.

I have a part-time work-from-home job (paid internship) and a couple thousand dollars, so I'm expecting that I can find a nearby place that I can afford at least for long enough to get more income. The main thing I'm worried about is legal barriers I don't know about - since my parents are not cooperating, I have no idea what to expect.

I do not have any sort of insurance and hope it won't be required. My research is finding that health insurance is not mandatory except in a few states (not mine), and renter's insurance is cheap enough to be insignificant (I'm seeing like $20/month) even if I do end up needing it. I think auto insurance is mandatory but I won't need it because I won't be owning a car (if I need a car to get to the place I rent, I'm planning on Uber or similar).

I do have a checking account and debit card (as well as a saving account).

So just to make sure, are there any legal obstacles to me just moving out and renting an appartment without cooperation from my parents?

Comment: Are you under any sort of guardianship order or court protection order?

Comment: I assume you are living in the US?

Comment: There is no country in the world where 22 is below the Age of Majority, so unless you're under some kind Power of Attorney/Guardianship, you can do what you like (although I guess there are countries that have different rules based on gender)

Comment: Where are you asking? Somali Renter Laws are quite different from German Mietrecht or the Hyderabad Rental Ordinances... In fact, the state, province and county, sometimes even the township, might have rules! For example, Berlin explicitly bans to use flats for RBNB or simminar services!

Comment: @Strawberry Some countries put parents on the hook by default till some given age.

Comment: Sorry, I should've specified I'm in the US. I don't know how guardianship arrangements work in the US. I will try to research them more. My parents told me they have some sort of guardianship arrangement that I know nothing about and for no reason I can imagine, and that they don't know how it works and refuse to find out.

Comment: Oh. If you're under guardianship, that could change everything. See the addition to my answer.

Comment: I think you should see a lawyer

Comment: Your question seems not primarily about renting, but about moving out. I edited the title to clarify, hope that's ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you in the United States? If so, you're an adult and therefore legally free to move out of your parents' home and to enter into contracts. As a legal matter, you don't really need to do much at all beyond turn 18 to be permitted to sign a lease.

There are of course all manner of practical impediments to finding a place to live (perhaps you have inadequate income, credit, or references), but none that should be insurmountable.

EDIT: You've indicated in the comments that you may be under a guardianship, but you seem to be indicating that you doubt whether this is true. If you are under a guardianship, your rights are likely to be quite different than under usual circumstances.

It seems quite unlikely to me that an adult who has the mental capacity to come asking these questions could be under a guardianship without knowing about it. Given that your parents are the purported guardians, I don't know how you could have been placed under their guardianship without appearing in court sometime around your 18th birthday, which I assume you'd remember.

You should determine whether you are under a guardianship. You can probably do this by searching the court records online for each county you've lived in. Alternatively, you could contact adult protective services or an equivalent agency.

Comment: Thanks! I also should've mentioned that some of my options involve crossing state borders (ie. renting an apartment without being personally there until the deal is closed). Does that change things?

Comment: I don't know of any reason you couldn't engage in interstate contract negotiations.